# @media print footer information overlap each other

Tags: html, css

I am using following css to create a footer when printing:

```
@media all {
   .page-break  { display: none; }
   .footer {display: none; }    
}

@media print {
   .page-break  { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
  .footer {display: block; position: fixed; bottom: 0; text-align: center; width:100%;}  
}
```

In html, I have something like:

```
<body>
  ...
  ...
 <div class='footer'>Page Number: 1</div>
 <div class='page-break'></div>
 ...
 ...
 <div class='footer'>Page Number: 2</div>
 <div class='page-break'></div>
 ...

</body>
```

Now the problem is, in printing view, the footer for page 1 and page 2, their content overlap each other.

I know this is caused by css "position: fixed; bottom 0". My question is: how to make footer for page 1 and page 2 still show up at the bottom of page 1 and page2 when in print view but they don't overlap each other?

Thanks.

Comment: you may provide a js fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can position one of them not in center.